# Why my router.push is ignoring part of my route path? VueJs

Tags: vue.js, button, path, vue-router

I'm new at Vue.js, and I'm trying to use router.push in my button to link it to my route, but, when I click it, it just ignores part of the string that I've put into it as part of the raw route path:

My button code:

```html
<div style="text-align: center; justifyContent: center; display: flex;">
    <Button label="Entrar" class="p-3 text-xl" style="width: 250px"
    @click="$router.push('app/dashboard')"></button>
</div>
```

My router.js:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name:'login_page',
        component: () => import('@/pages/Login')
    },
    {
        path: '/app',
        name: 'app',
        component: App,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/dashboard',
                name: 'dashboard',
                component: () => import('./components/Dashboard.vue')
            }
        ]
    }
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

[image: SC from the link generated]

It works, but with this link (see image above) instead of localhost:8080/app/dashboard, could someone explain to me why it does work and why it's not going to localhost:8080/app/dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

> Note that nested paths that start with `/` will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

Comment: Man, thanks for the answer, I was going crazy knowing that it should be simple. Thanks :)